# Disabling Mac OS X Mail.app periodic SMTP server check

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, apple-mail, smtp, keychain

My Mail.app is configured with three IMAP accounts and four SMTP servers.  (Each SMTP server is for a particular network connection.)  Every 10 minutes, Mail.app polls the SMTP servers to test connectivity

That by itself isn't a problem.  The issue is that these two SMTP servers require usernames and passwords.  Those credentials are stored in the account keychain, so every 10 minutes I'm prompted to unlock my account keychain.  That is six interruptions an hour, and is quite annoying.  Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure if it’s possible but, have you tried creating a new Keychain to hold those values exclusively? If that works, then you could make that keychain only lock when you logoff.

I’m not sure ifyou can move those values to a new keychain tho’-

Try the Keychain Access app.

Comment: Good idea -- I'll try that out and hopefully have an answer in the next 10 minutes or so...

Comment: This did the trick.  I created a new keychain and dragged the SMTP authentication credentials from the display of the 'login' keychain to the new keychain.  Then I changed the keychain settings by right-clicking on the new keychain, selecting "Change Settings...", and unchecking the two "Lock..." settings.

Comment: Glad it worked Peter. No more annoying popups. ;)